# Android: InflateException on composite component

Tags: android, composite-component, inflate

I'm creating a pretty complex composite component which throws an InflateException with an unknown cause. I was able to replicate the error in a simplified version below, which is just a component with two text views. Any help in identifying the error or tracking it down would be appreciated.

**composite_component.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.cc.CompositeComponent 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="One"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.cc.CompositeComponent>
```

**CompositeComponent.java**

```
package com.cc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CompositeComponent extends LinearLayout {

    public CompositeComponent(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public CompositeComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attributes){
        super(context, attributes);
    }

    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.composite_component, this);
    }
}
```

**CompositeActivity.java**

```
package com.cc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CompositeActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.composite_component);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="CompositeComponent">
    <activity android:name="CompositeActivity"
              android:label="CompositeComponent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

In your `composite_component.xml` file, try changing this line:

```
<com.cc.CompositeComponent
```

to the following:

```
<LinearLayout
```

And then, create a second layout that your activity passes to `setContentView()`:

**File:** `composite_activity_layout.xml`

```
<com.cc.CompositeComponent
    android:id="@+id/my_composite"
    <!-- other stuff ->>
```

**File:** `CompositeActivity.java`

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle state ) {
    super.onCreate( state );

    setContentView(R.layout.composite_activity_layout);
    // ...
}
```

What it looks like you are doing is causing a recursive layout inflation.  You inflate `CompositeComponent`, and then in the `onFinishInflate()` method, `CompositeComponent` inflates another copy of itself.

Also, you may want to investigate the use of [Android's merge tag](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) to avoid having that extra `LinearLayout` hanging around.

Comment: Thanks for the UNBELIEVABLY fast response! It appears that you're correct about the recursive inflation. I split it into two files as you suggested and it solves the issue. However I don't like the idea of adding yet another level of layout containers - the ui is pretty deep already. I may have to do that, but I'm also seeing if I can use the merge tag as also suggested.

Comment: Cool - glad it helped.  The merge tag should help you eliminate the extra container.   Also, if you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: After further investigation merge will not work in my situation, but your answer was instrumental in addressing the issue....thanks a ton